# how to fetch a cell from excel using java whether the cell may contains a string or numeric value?

Tags: java, excel

Here is my code:

```
long tin=0; 
tin = (long)row.getCell(10).getNumericCellValue();
```

tin value of excel may contains string or only numeric value..
if tin value is numeric am able to fetch data..
if tin value is String am getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the type of the cell using [Cell#getCellTypeEnum()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellTypeEnum()). Possible returned values are:

- _NONE - Unknown type, used to represent a state prior to initialization or the lack of a concrete type.
- BLANK  - Blank cell type
- BOOLEAN - Boolean cell type
- ERROR - Error cell type
- FORMULA - Formula cell type
- NUMERIC - Numeric cell type (whole numbers, fractional numbers, dates)
- STRING - String (text) cell type

In other words you should try the following scaffold:

```
tin = row.getCell(10).getCellTypeEnum().equals(CellType.NUMERIC) ? 
     (long)row.getCell(10).getNumericCellValue() :
     Long.parseLong(row.getCell(10).getStringCellValue());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply can you be more specific.?am a beginner.

Comment: Basically check if the field is numeric first and then decide whether you can get the value or not

Comment: The method getCellTypeEnum() is undefined for the type HSSFCell

Comment: No i just want the data either it is a string or numeric value doesn't matter

Comment: @ManjunathReddy https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCell.html#getCellTypeEnum()

Comment: @ManjunathReddy if you're using old Apache Poi, try getCellType() which returns a String

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137041/discussion-between-manjunath-reddy-and-xenteros).